# WordPress: Unknown 404 error in console

Tags: wordpress, console, http-status-code-404, doctype

While its not affecting the site it bugs me that I can't get rid of this 404 error in the console. When I view the page I get this message:

http://myproject.dev/undefined 404 (Not Found)

And when I click to see what it refers to it points to the same line as my doctype declaration, which is a standard . I run a few php variables before this but I tried to swap them out and I still get the message.

I've set up my WP site so that it defaults to a page and this page runs on the default page.php template. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure inside your header, you're not calling an script or file that does not exist?

Comment: Thanks, yes I've checked for that.